# How do you extract the height from NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I wish to add extra height on my TabBar. I have used CarbonKit scrollable tabbar.
When I ty to get the toolbar height  I manage to get a statement saying something is height of 40 (I assume it is the tabbar height). I wish to extract the 40 out and add extra 30 to it to the height. How do I do that?

```
    let carbonTabSwipeNavigation = CarbonTabSwipeNavigation(items: images, delegate: self)

    carbonTabSwipeNavigation.insert(intoRootViewController: self)

    let tabBarHeight = carbonTabSwipeNavigation.toolbarHeight

    print("the Tab Bar Height = " , tabBarHeight)
```

the Tab Bar Height = NSLayoutConstraint:0x2835d8e60 UIToolbar:0x10dd5d160.height == 40   (active)

How to I get the 40 out of the statement? I try casting it to integer but fail

```
    carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setTabBarHeight(tabBarHeight+tabBarExtraHeight)
```

The above code is will give me error because I can't add them together.

Comment: As a side note, if you're learning iOS development, the last thing I would do is use third-party modules for basic things like tab bar navigation and swipe to refresh. Learn it! And if you do become a go-to developer, you're never going to use these 3rd parties anyway. To your question, when you command-click `tabBarHeight` in `let tabBarHeight = carbonTabSwipeNavigation.toolbarHeight` and select `Show Quick Help`, what is the type of that constant?

Comment: Are you sure passing(both variable) float value to that method? Otherwise give value like 

tabSwipe.setTabBarHeight(100)

What error stating?\

Comment: Yes giving value of tabSwipe.setTabBarHeight(100) has no problem but will at iPAD the height will be too small, I want it to be extra height so at all platform it will be the same.